# If every consistent set of sentences has a model then has every consistent set of formulas a model?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a languange and let $F\left(\mathcal{L}\right)$
be the corresponding set of formulas in F.O.L.

I encountered a concise script on logics/structure with a nice deduction system on base of the connectives $\wedge$,
$\to$, $\bot$ and $\forall$ where derivations are presented as binary trees by means
of identity axioms and the following rules:

- $\wedge$ elimination
- $\wedge$ introduction
- Modus Ponens
- Deduction-rule
- Reductio ad Absurdum
- Generalization
- Instantiation

The system deals with all elements of $F(\mathcal L)$ (i.e. formulas) and the script contains a proof of soundness.

Also there is a proof of the following statement:

> If $\Sigma$ is
> a set of **sentences** that is (syntactically) consistent (i.e. $\Sigma\nvdash\bot$)
> then $\Sigma$ has a model.

However, what I am really after (as counterpart of soundness) is actually a proof of:

> If $\Sigma$ is
> a set of **formulas** that is (syntactically) consistent (i.e. $\Sigma\nvdash\bot$)
> then $\Sigma$ has a model.

The fact that only sentences are dealt with makes me suspect that there is some obvious extension from sentences to formulas (and I hope that is true), but unfortunately I cannot find it.

Thank you in advance for taking notice of my question.

Comment: Hint: If you have a free variable in a formula, what does it mean for that formula to have a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First prove a lemma: Let $L'$ be a language which includes constant symbols $\{c_i\mid i\in I\}$ (and possibly other constant symbols too), and let $L = L'\setminus \{c_i\mid i\in I\}$. Let $\Delta'\vdash \varphi'$ be a derivation in the language $L'$. Let $\Delta$ and $\varphi$ be obtained from $\Delta'$ and $\varphi'$ by replacing all instances of each constant symbol $c_i$ by a fresh variable $x_i$. Then $\Delta\vdash \varphi$ is a derivation in the language $L$.

This should be an easy induction on the structure of the proof.

Now suppose $\Sigma$ is a consistent set of $L$-formulas. Enumerate the free variables appearing in the formulas in $\Sigma$ as $\{x_i\mid i\in I\}$. For each variable $x_i$, let $c_i$ be new constant symbol, and let $L' = L\cup \{c_i\mid i\in I\}$. Let $\Sigma'$ be the set of $L'$-sentences obtained by substituting $c_i$ for each free instance of $x_i$ in $\Sigma$. By the lemma, $\Sigma'$ is consistent: if $\Sigma'\vdash \bot$ is a derivation in the language $L'$, then $\Sigma\vdash \bot$ is a derivation in the language $L$, since $\Sigma$ is obtained from $\Sigma'$ (up to possibly renaming variables) by replacing each constant $c_i$ with the variable $x_i$.

Now you can use your theorem about consistent sets of sentences to see that there is an $L'$-structure $M'$ which is a model of $\Sigma'$. Letting $M$ be the reduct of $M'$ to $L$, we have that $(M;(c_i^{M'})_{i\in I})$ is a model of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Looks good at first sight (I will need some time of thinking and checking). Are there no problems if the number of free variables is not finite (first thought)?

Comment: @drhab Oh, I implicitly applied compactness here: only finitely many of the formulas actually appear in any derivation. Let me edit to clarify this.

Comment: @drhab I think the cleanest thing to do is to allow arbitrary sets of constants and free variables from the start. This won't change the proof of the lemma at all (since every inductive step involves only finitely many formulas).

Comment: Yes, I think it works! Thank you very much, Alex.